# While implementing the page object modelling using page factory with selenium webdriver, which is the good approach out of the two?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, browser-automation

1. Calling `public static <T> T initElements(WebDriver driver, java.lang.Class<T> pageClassToProxy)`
   within each method which navigates to the target webpage class page ?

Or

2. Calling `public static <T> T initElements(WebDriver driver, java.lang.Class<T> pageClassToProxy)`
   in the constructor of the webpage class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it's intended to be is to place your call to `PageFactory.InitElements()` in the constructor of the class representing the web page. If you have classes representing a certain object on the page (like header or footer, that occur on several pages), you can call it there, too. The object doesn't have to be a webpage.

Comment: thank you Kim for your valuable advice. I will try in my framework..and accordingly in case if I come across any doubt I will post it here ..thanks a lot once again for your time.